# Error when call function using javascript on facebook init?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: appId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

   this.test();  
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
this.test = function() {
    alert('test');
}
```

When I call function `test()` on FB init is result is "`TypeError: this.test is not a function`", how to fix it ?

Comment: @AndrewII Changing the spelling of Javascript is not a big enough change for a whole edit. Please stop.

Answer (score 0):

Scope problem, remove "this" when you call the test function. "This" refers to the fbAsyncInit function.

New code (untested, but should work):

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: appId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

   test();  
};
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
function test () {
    alert('test');
}
```

Comment: remove "this" on the outside too. just define it like this:
function test() {
   alert('test');
}

Answer (score 0):

`this` in function and `this` in global scope are links to different objects; you can replace `this` with `window` it would work.